# System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: true, Actual: false ? True is expected

Tags: trigger, unit-test, before-trigger, triggercontext

I am testing my piece of trigger

```
trigger problemOne on Account (before insert , after insert , before update) 
{
    if(Trigger.isBefore)
    {
        //If new record is created : 
        if(Trigger.isInsert)
        {
            for(Account acc : Trigger.new)
            {
                acc.Only_Default_Contact__c = TRUE;
            }
        }
        
    }
    if(Trigger.isAfter)
    {
        List<Contact> listContact =  new List<Contact>();
        //After Insertion is Successful :
         if(Trigger.isInsert)
         {
             for(Account acc : Trigger.new)
             {
                Contact temp = new Contact();
                temp.AccountId= acc.id;
                temp.FirstName= 'Info';
                temp.LastName= 'mation dummy'; 
                temp.Email = 'infor@mation.com';
                 listContact.add(temp);
             }
             insert listContact;
         }
    }
}
```

Test Code :

```
@isTest
public class problemOneTest 
{

    @isTest
    public static void problemOne()
    {
        List<Account> listAccount =  new List<Account>();
        for(integer i=0 ; i<50 ;i++)
        {
            Account acc = new Account (Name = 'test account data');
            listAccount.add(acc);
        }
        insert listAccount;
        for(Account acco : listAccount)
        {
            System.assertEquals(true, acco.Only_Default_Contact__c);
        }
        
        integer sizeCheck = [Select count() from contact where firstName='Info'];
        System.assertEquals(50, sizeCheck);
    }
}
```

**In Actual Account Only Default Contact value is checked(TRUE) but Still getting this one :
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: true, Actual: false**

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 15 of your test, you should query the account records back from Database using SOQL and assert them.

Right now you are asserting on in memory records i.e. the list you created.

Comment: Thankyou Manjit :)